# Multiple find and replace in PowerPoint with Excel sheet

Tags: excel, replace, find, powerpoint

I am trying to customize the script in the webpage below to find and replace words and phrases in a PowerPoint document using a pre-defined Excel list. The code below worked best for me but I need to use with long replacement lists. I have tried many times but failed to get the correct array.
The excel list is very long and has two columns with headers: "Find what" and "Replace with"

Excel document name: Offices.xlsx

Path: C:\Users\JL\Docuemnts

Sheet name:  Sheet1

I get this error: (Run-time error '424': Object required) at this line:

Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\JL\Docuemnts\Offices.xlsx")"

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you

(Source script: https://www.msofficeforums.com/powerpoint/20104-find-replace-macro.html)

```
Sub PPTFindAndReplace()
Dim oPres As Presentation
Dim oSld As Slide
Dim oShp As Shape
Dim FindWhat As String
Dim ReplaceWith As String
Dim x As Integer
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\JL\Docuemnts\Offices.xlsx")
myArray = Workbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a2:a200").Value
myArray2 = Workbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("b2:b200").Value
FindWhat = myArray(x)
ReplaceWith = myArray2(x)
For Each oPres In Application.Presentations
For Each oSld In oPres.Slides
For Each oShp In oSld.Shapes
Call ReplaceText(oShp, FindWhat, ReplaceWith)
Next oShp
Next oSld
Next oPres
End Sub
Sub ReplaceText(oShp As Object, FindString As String, ReplaceString As String)
Dim oTxtRng As TextRange
Dim oTmpRng As TextRange
Dim I As Integer
Dim iRows As Integer
Dim iCols As Integer
Dim oShpTmp As Shape

' Always include the 'On error resume next' statement below when you are working with text range object.
' I know of at least one PowerPoint bug where it will error out - when an image has been dragged/pasted
' into a text box. In such a case, both HasTextFrame and HasText properties will return TRUE but PowerPoint
' will throw an error when you try to retrieve the text.

On Error Resume Next
Select Case oShp.Type
Case 19 'msoTable
For iRows = 1 To oShp.Table.Rows.Count
For iCol = 1 To oShp.Table.Rows(iRows).Cells.Count
Set oTxtRng = oShp.Table.Rows(iRows).Cells(iCol).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange
Set oTmpRng = oTxtRng.Replace(FindWhat:=FindString, _
ReplaceWhat:=ReplaceString, WholeWords:=False)
Do While Not oTmpRng Is Nothing
Set oTmpRng = oTxtRng.Replace(FindWhat:=FindString, _
ReplaceWhat:=ReplaceString, _
After:=oTmpRng.Start + oTmpRng.Length, _
WholeWords:=False)
Loop
Next
Next
Case msoGroup 'Groups may contain shapes with text, so look within it
For I = 1 To oShp.GroupItems.Count
Call ReplaceText(oShp.GroupItems(I), FindString, ReplaceString)
Next I
Case 21 ' msoDiagram
For I = 1 To oShp.Diagram.Nodes.Count
Call ReplaceText(oShp.Diagram.Nodes(I).TextShape, FindString, ReplaceString)
Next I
Case Else
If oShp.HasTextFrame Then
If oShp.TextFrame.HasText Then
Set oTxtRng = oShp.TextFrame.TextRange
Set oTmpRng = oTxtRng.Replace(FindWhat:=FindString, _
ReplaceWhat:=ReplaceString, WholeWords:=False)
Do While Not oTmpRng Is Nothing
Set oTmpRng = oTxtRng.Replace(FindWhat:=FindString, _
ReplaceWhat:=ReplaceString, _
After:=oTmpRng.Start + oTmpRng.Length, _
WholeWords:=False)
Loop
End If
End If
End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: You haven't DIMmed wb prior to using it in the line of code that throws the error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now with "Dim wb As Workbook", I get a "user-defined type not defined" error.

Comment: I assumed you were running this from within Excel and had set references to PowerPoint. 
 Probably not. If in PPT, you'll either need to set a reference to Excel or Dim wb as Object instead of Workbook.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg  The workbook has been set correctly now and it's opening correctly but another error is appearing (Subscript out range) in this line: FindWhat = myArray(x)

Comment: And you'd see the same error in the next line. You've created a variable x but haven't assigned any value to it. By the way, strictly speaking, x should be DIMmed as Long rather than as an Integer. You need to do something like: for each shape in the slide, for each element in the array, do the text replacement on the text.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Thanks for the tips. I managed to fix my script.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg How can I add a second sheet with a different range  ("Sheet2) to my array ? myArray = Workbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a2:a200")

Comment: If I understand your intent correctly, I think I'd modify the original Subroutine to take a string parameter (ie, the sheet name) and use that parameter rather than a hard coded sheet name. You could then simply call the routine for each sheet you want to work with.

Comment: That's a great idea. Thank you for the tip.